# Selenium Cucumber ruby code for element count

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Good Day All,
Can you please help me to get the number of transaction on a banking page using selenium webdriver - cucumber - ruby.
Please help me .
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We might need much more information than that in order to give you an accurate answer. However here's some code to give you an idea:

`When (/^I get transaction number/) do
    selector = "your_selector_goes_here"
    $transaction = page.find(:xpath, selector).text
end`

Later you could access the text stored in `$transaction` and do whatever you need with it.